# batch script loop in win cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

**I need to merge multiple ".ts" files in each directory.**
The file structure is like this:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMIt6.jpg)

I've tried loop code and it worked well in a one-layer structure:

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,24) do (
    copy /b %%x\*.ts new_%%x.ts
)
pause
```

I tried to add another loop to run a double-layer structure, it won't work in the following code:

```
for /l %%x in (1,24,49) do (
    for /l %%a in (%%x,1,%%x+23) do (
        copy /b %%x\%%a\*.ts \%%x\new_%%a.ts
    )
)
```

**The problem is the values can't be summed here:**

```
%%x+23
```

Then I tried to calculate the value before putting it in the second loop:

```
for /l %%x in (1,24,49) do (
    set /a endvalue=%%x+23
    for /l %%a in (%%x,1,endvalue) do (
        copy /b %%x\%%a\*.ts \%%x\new_%%a.ts
    )
)
```

And the code still doesn't work.

Did I miss something? How can I fix it?

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delayed environment variable expansion

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1,24,49) do (
    set /a beginvalue=%%x
    set /a endvalue=%%x + 23
    for /l %%a in (!beginvalue!,1,!endvalue!) do (
        echo %%a
    )
)
```